# Sapui5 QUnit testing errors through class not found exceptions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, sapui5

I am going through this (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/guide/a6b0657d226343da81ad96632cd1bd83.html) guide.

The problems are:

```
sap.ui.test.qunit.triggerKeydown()
```

is undefined. The documentation is available here (http://www.spyvee.com/SAPHTML5_DemoKit/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.qunit.html), but not on (https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.html).

[image]

And next point:

```
sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger()
```

is undefined. How can I load the proper resources (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger.html)?

What I know so far:

```
sap.ui.core.routing //is defined but only contains the HistoryDirection Object
Object {HistoryDirection: Object}
```

And to the second point:

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.test.library"); //retuns the Uncaught Error
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/test/library.js' from https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/test/library.js: 404 - Not Found
```

How ca I get my test to work?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** `sap.ui.test.qunit.triggerKeydown();` is undefined

**Solution:**  `jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.test.TestUtils");`

---

**Problem:** `sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger();` is undefined

**Solution:**  `jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger");`